# (local)\MSSQLSERVERConnection could not be established

Tags: php, sql-server-2014

[image]

i have no idea how to connect PHP to sqlsrv.  i've installed and enabled all the extensions in php.ini.

What service/instance information am I supposed to use to configure my connection string??!

Comment: So you ask us, to rewrite the code you've written and make changes it so it does work? I'm just to lazy to the first part of that, as you are by not searching `php connect mssql` in any given search engine.

Answer (score 0):

You have serious problems in your connection string.

Go here to generate your valid connection string :

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/sql-connection-string/